# Token mismatch exception only on every first attempt laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

Every time I log in to my application for the first time after an hour or so or on every new device I get token mismatch exception. But when I try again right after the problem goes away. I am using 755 on storage/framework/sessions -- I have the same problem on my local vagrant scotch box 1.5 box as well as onmy Digital Ocean LAMP. Any ideas?

Comment: Is "POST /login" the first request you send to your application?

Comment: the route that I use is an "any" type. Route::any('training/authenticate', 'trainingController@authenticate');  -- should this change?

Comment: And are you sending a token with the request?

Comment: Yes, I just don't understand why it happens only first time I login on a given device, the second attempt always works flawlessly

Comment: I'm guessing here, but if you're getting token mismatch error it means the token you provide is invalid or expired. Is it possible that when you try to login for the first time after some hours from the last request you are using the token you got in the previous session? It would be expired so that could cause the error. Then when the first login attempt fails you're getting a new token and use that in subsequent attempts. That would be the reason why only the first attempt fails

Comment: Thanks jedrzej.kurylo, But my question remains unanswered. I can't tell users to try logging in twice because the first attempt will always fail. You see my point? I even have that same issue if I reload the page upon visiting for the first time. I don't know why the token does not match only the first time.

Comment: are You using CSRF middleware? and if YES so is it really needed?

Comment: I got the same problem. Also with a local Apache (EasyPHP) the first login fails, second login works, everyday.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the CSRF Token has expired and your browser need a new token to make POST request.
The expiration time by default in Laravel is 2 hours.

I have the same problem and I am trying this solution https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/crsf-checked-before-auth

**UPDATE:**

You need to update the render method in app/Exceptions/Handler.php and handle the Exception: TokenMismatchException

Code Example

```
   /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
            return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Sorry, your session seems to have expired. Please login again.');
        }

        if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't but tell you that if you're coding for a Laravel project you should give homestead box a try, I'm using it for a year now and no weird issues have happened and my logins work flawlessly out of the box.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead

Maybe this can help you out quicker than figuring out the issue on your current box :)

Comment: This didn't even try to help solve the issue, suggesting homestead when he is using a Digital Ocean VPS doesn't make sense.